# Sending an array in a query string to PHP via Angular 6

Tags: php, angular, http

Ahoy!
I'm working on getting an Angular app to send a get request to my backend which is written in PHP. Currently my PHP code is expecting three parameters including two strings and an array of strings. An example would be something like this...

```
domain?method=get_card_info&team[]=Raichu&team[]=Raichu&generation=7
```

but when I send the info to my back end and error log the result I get

```
domain?method=get_card_info&team%5B%5D=Raichu&team%5B%5D=Raichu&generation=7
```

with the square brackets encoded. Here's my code to send the request...

```
getPokemon(name: string) {

  let myParams = new HttpParams();
  myParams = myParams.append('method', 'get_card_info');
  myParams = myParams.append('team[]', name);
  myParams = myParams.append('team[]', name);
  myParams = myParams.append('generation', '7');

  return this.http.get('http://localhost/pokemon/ajax.php', {
    params: myParams
  });
}
```

Is there a way to do it so that the square brackets don't get encoded? Or will I need to change my back end code to accommodate?
Thanks!

Comment: use `.post` instead of `.get`. Also what's the purpose of sending `[]` there?

Comment: If possible send your data as post method

Comment: You can also keep using `get` but separate your strings with a comma then parse it in your backend.

Comment: So I took the advice in the first two comments and switched to using post. I had to wrestle with it but I got it to work. Thanks for the suggestion of using comma separated values as well. There's a good chance I'll make use of that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So a couple people commented that I should use post instead of get and that's what I ended up doing. After a bit of tweaking and some CORS related stuff I got it to work though I had to modify my backend code as well.
Thanks for the help.